# 1 out of 10 times click function was trigger by clicking select instead of clicking option?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I hit the select, 1 out of 10 times it will trigger the click function when I just click select. But, I want to trigger the click function when I click the select option. What did I do wrong, what should I do to trouble shoot this? By the way, this code is inside my ajax function.

```js
$('#pagination select option').click(function(e){
    alert('test');
                    $this = $(this).val();
     window.location.hash = $this;
   });
```

```html
<div id="pagination">
          <span href='prev' id='prev'>Prev</span>
             <select > 
    <?php for( $i= 0 ; $i < $post_count ; $i++ ){
     ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i;?>" <?php if($i==$post_pagination_num){echo "selected=selected";};?>><?php echo $i+1;?></option>
     <?php
    }
    ?> 
    </select>  
       <span href='next' id='next'>Next</span>
```

Comment: Don't add PHP, add generated HTML instead

Comment: #kz_pagination or #pagination only? the specified Id is invalid.

Comment: why don't add php, what is the different?

Answer (score 2):

Use change event

```
$('#pagination select').change(function(e){
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h3njg4zj/)